# Inserindo aspas simples em campos nulos

Tags: c#, .net, string, entity-framework, postgresql

Criei uma aplicação bem simples pra simular um pequeno cadastro de clientes, porém ao testar a manipulação de dados pela aplicação pude ver na base de dados que os campos que ficam nulos no cadastro são inseridos na base de dados com duas aspas simples ('').

Em outras aplicações eu consigo resolver isto mudando o tipo de dado do parâmetro para `NpgsqlDbType.Text`, porém não conheço uma forma de fazer isto no EF.

Utilizo uma classe POCO de entidade mapeada desta forma:

```
[Table("cliente", Schema = "public")]
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome não pode ser nulo.")]
    [Column("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    [Column("endereco")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }


    [Column("bairro", TypeName="text")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cidade não pode ser nulo.")]
    [Column("cidade")]
    public int CidadeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CidadeID")]
    public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }

    [Column("cpfcnpj")]
    public string CPFCNPJ { get; set; }

    [Column("telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Column("ativo")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }

}
```

Abaixo método que insere os dados do cliente informado no formulário na base de dados:

```
    public static void InserirCliente(Cliente cli)
    {
        using (var db = new Repositorio.DBContexto())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Clientes.Add(cli);
                var usuarioSalvo = db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Abaixo método do evento iniciado pelo Click de um botão Salvar:

```
    private void btnSalvar_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.Nome = Convert.ToString(txtNome.EditValue);
            cliente.Telefone = Convert.ToString(txtTelefone.EditValue);
            cliente.CPFCNPJ = Convert.ToString(txtCPF.EditValue);

            cliente.Endereco = Convert.ToString(txtEndereco.EditValue);
            cliente.Bairro = Convert.ToString(txtBairro.EditValue);
            cliente.CidadeID = Convert.ToInt32(lkeCidade.EditValue);
            cliente.Ativo = true;

            DAL.ClienteDAL.InserirCliente(cliente);

            MessageBox.Show("Cliente Inserido com Sucesso!", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}\n\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException), "Ooops", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Existe alguma forma de evitar que seja inserido as "aspas simples" em campos que permitem valores nulos?

Comment: Então... tentei utilizar utilizar string? e tmb Nullable<string> mas obtenho um erro de compilação pois string já um tipo que prevê nulos...

Comment: Quais campos dá o problema? São só os de tipo *string*? Eles estão nulos? Se eles não estão, o comportamento está correto. Se quer gravar nulos, precisa garantir que estejam nulos.

Comment: Dá uma lida sobre exceções que não é assim que se faz: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]

Comment: então cara... não que isso seja supérfluo mas abrir uma tabela e ver aquele monte de aspas simples me incomoda, e além do mais posso ter problemas com cláusulas onde o campo é nulo ou não nulo...

Comment: na minha pequena base de testes apenas informei em campos do tipo character varying... Mas ainda a pouco testei com o o tipo boolean e o nulo foi numa boa...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que os dados na aplicação estão como *string* vazia e não como nula, então grava uma *string* vazia. Se deseja gravar um nulo no banco de dados precisa garantir que o dado seja nulo.

Se o dado já é nulo, basta fazer isto:

```
cliente.Nome = txtNome.EditValue;
```

Não vejo porque fazer uma conversão para *string* de algo que já é *string*. A conversão de um nulo para *string* dá um vazio e não um objeto com valor nulo, conforme demonstra a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToString_System_Object_). O erro está aí, por isso os demais campos funcionam.

Aproveitando, se houver alguma chance de não ter um número válido no campo de valor inteiro abaixo, haverá uma exceção desnecessária (isto é erro de programação):

```
Convert.ToInt32(lkeCidade.EditValue)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/EmptyString.cs).

Também, nunca deve-se capturar uma exceção só para relançá-la. Isto só causa problemas. Se não tem nada útil para fazer quando captura uma exceção, não a capture.

Capturar `Exception` também não costuma ser adequado na maioria das situações. Assim como tentar fechar algumas coisas sem um padrão de projeto que garanta que isto será fechado. O código atual pode vazar recursos abertos facilmente.

Comment: Só um comentário... o objeto lkeCidade é uma lista de cidades, contendo como 'ValueMember' o ID da cidade. Este campo tem tratamento para não ser nulos ou qualquer valor que não esteja na lista, logo, a conversão não terá possibilidade de dar erro...  Sobre o Convert.toString()...  O objeto do tipo textbox (devexpress) tem a propriedade 'EditValue' do tipo 'Object'... Sua conversão é necessária...   Estou lendo mais sobre tratamento de exceções... Realmente estava fazendo algumas coisas erradas...

Comment: Melhor assim. Fique atento para outros casos onde isto não seja garantido.

Answer (score 1):

Graças ao comentário do colega Maniero fui me certificar que o valor do campo era nulo... Adicionei uma validação na conversão dos valores para o objeto `Cliente` e bingo!

Basicamente adicionei esta validação na passagem de valores.

```
 cliente.Bairro = (txtBairro.EditValue == null ? null : Convert.ToString(txtBairro.EditValue));
```